# Should a model contain all of the data required to build the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Lets say I have a site that has a Layout with navigation.  This navigation is built each time a page is requested based on options the user has chosen.  This navigation does not really have anything to do with the particular view being presented except that it is required for the Layout.  The question is, should this be put in the ViewData or should the Model be required to inherit a NavigationModel?

```
ViewBag.NavItems = navItems;
```

or

```
public abstract class NavigationModel
{
    public List<NavItem> NavItems { get; set;}
}

public class HomeModel : NavigationModel
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like an ideal case to use `Html.RenderAction` inside of the view to render the navigation. This would call an action on a `NavigationController` that would be responsible for rendering the menu directly into the view.

Some MVC purists feel that `Html.RenderAction` breaks true MVC architecture; I see it as a way of delegating responsibility to render certain parts of the view that are not the primary responsibility of the "main" view that you're rendering.

Comment: Perhaps, or @Html.Partial("Navigation", HomeModel) where Navigation has a Model type of NavigationModel.  Doesnt RenderAction run the whole pipe again just for that action??

Comment: With `RenderPartial` though, you now need to supply the model that you're going to pass into the Navigation partial view. You'll thus need to have it on the model being passed into the main view. Before you know it, your model has 10 properties on it that are models to satisfy the partial views in the view!

Comment: Yes, interesting trade off.  I am in the boat right now of having all the props on the model, and they are easy to satisfy as I use the OnActionExecuted in the controller to set them, but if you dont think its too heavy to use RenderAction I like that solution... which I used to use.

Comment: I've heard (although not looked into) some *possible* performance with RenderAction but as with all performance related *potential* issues, (1) don't worry about it until/unless it's a problem and (2) you need to benchmark it vs. other approaches :) edit: found this reply from Brad Wilson - http://forums.asp.net/t/1502235.aspx/1

Comment: Interesting link.  Brad confirmed what I thought in that the whole pipe must be run to process the RenderAction, while the RenderPartial will just render what I pass it.  I do agree its not good to prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 2):

> Should a model contain all of the data required to build the view?

Absolutely and definitely YES.

> The question is, should this be put in the ViewData

Absolutely and definitely NO.

You also have the possibility of using [Html.Action and Html.RenderAction](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) if this navigation widget could be considered as fully independent part of your site.

Comment: Additionally, the data should be materialized before being added to the view model!  Queries executed in views melt faces.

Comment: I totally agree with that, but does the RenderAction inside a view not munge the borders a bit?  It means you need to go back to the controller to get more data that you forgot to get to render the view?!  How is this different than using RenderAction like a repo?

Comment: @CrazyDart I prefer using ViewData for navigation view models and populating it via a global action filter, but I understand using RenderAction can be more familiar for some programmers. Either works.